# Delay before sending ajax request does not work

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, jquery-hover

When I do hover over `<td>` it does wait 900 milliseconds and then sends a lot of requests (I always hover over more tds in these 900ms). What am I doing wrong? why only `clearTimeout`  (commented)  works?

My point is to wait before hitting server and if user move mouse to another `<td>` in this running countdown (900ms), previous countdown is aborted and new one takes place

```
        $(function(){
                var isLoading = false;
                $("td").hover(function(){
                        var x = parseInt(0);
                        var position = $(this).attr('id');
                        clearTimeout(timer);
                        var oID = $(this).attr('id');
                        var oData = $(this);
                        var timer = setTimeout(function(){
                                if (position == oID&&!isLoading)
                                {
                                        clearTimeout(timer);
                                        $.ajax({
                                                beforeSend: function(xhr){ var isLoading = true; },
                                                url: 'ajax.php?what=click&position='+position,
                                                success: function(data){
                                                        $('#hovercard').css(oData.offset());
                                                        $('#hovercard').show();
                                                        $('#hovercard').html(data);
                                                }
                                        });
                                }
                        }, 900);
// this only works ->                                             clearTimeout(timer);
                });
        });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to store `timer` in a scope outside the hover function. I'm not so sure about the scope for `isLoading` either, so if this doesn't work, try moving `isLoading` out to the same scope as `timer`:

```
    var timer;
    $(function(){
            var isLoading = false;
            $("td").hover(function(){
                    var x = parseInt(0);
                    var position = $(this).attr('id');
                    clearTimeout(timer);
                    var oID = $(this).attr('id');
                    var oData = $(this);
                    timer = setTimeout(function(){
                        if (position == oID&&!isLoading)
                        {
                                clearTimeout(timer);
                                $.ajax({
                                        beforeSend: function(xhr){ isLoading = true; },
                                        url: 'ajax.php?what=click&position='+position,
                                        success: function(data){
                                                    $('#hovercard').css(oData.offset());
                                                    $('#hovercard').show();
                                                    $('#hovercard').html(data);
                                        }
                                });
                        }
                   }, 900);
           });
   });
```

You have some other oddities as well. Note that oID always will be equal to position as they are set at the same time, in the same scope. This makes the first condition in your if statement pointless. I've also removed the `var` statement in your beforeSend function.